# Is after Truncate Table constraints exist in SQL?

Tags: sql

When we Truncate Table in SQL then all the all records from but table exist. I want to know constraints,indexs remain exist or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constraints and indexes will remain. Truncate also resets any auto-incremented IDs to zero.

Answer (score 2):

Truncate only removes the records in the table.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177570.aspx) (TRUNCATE TABLE):

> TRUNCATE TABLE is similar to the DELETE statement with no WHERE clause;

Answer (score 2):

constraints,indexes remain. For more information [check this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260621%28SQL.80%29.aspx)